# Simple Differential Geometry/Analysis question: Prove that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

In Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Manfredo do Carmo, page 459, it says the following: Observe that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, where $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} -1$ . My analysis is a little bit rusty--how do you prove that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: This is only true if and only if $a, b \neq 0$. In any case, this is a polynomial, it must always be continuous.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you, those are great, I was wondering if there was a nice  ϵ−δ proof. I wanted to find the δ such that if $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 <$ $δ^2$, then $|f(x,y) - f(x_0, y_0)| <$  ϵ. I am not sure how to find the δ.

Comment: Why?!! That's why you have theorems.

Comment: I needed some practice and to see how to prove with ϵ−δ proof. I was trying it out before the remark by 'Nameless', which is quite obvious and clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $(c,d)\in \Bbb R^2$. Set $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{\lambda}\}$, where $$\lambda := \frac{1 + 2|c|}{a^2} + \frac{1 + 2|d|}{b^2}.$$ Given $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$, if $(x - c)^2 + (y - d)^2 < \delta^2$, then $|x - c| < \delta$ and $|y - d| < \delta$. In particular, $|x - c| < 1$ and $|y - d| < 1$, which implies $|x + c| \le |x - c| + 2|c| < 1 + 2|c|$, and similarly $|y - d| < 1 + 2|d|$. Hence

\begin{align}|f(x,y) - f(c,d)| &= \left\lvert \frac{x^2 - c^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2 - d^2}{b^2}\right\rvert \\
&\le \frac{|x^2 - c^2|}{a^2} + \frac{|y^2 - d^2|}{b^2}\\
&=\frac{|x - c||x + c|}{a^2} + \frac{|y - d||y + d|}{b^2}\\
&< \frac{\delta(1 + 2|c|)}{a^2} + \frac{\delta(1 + 2|d|)}{b^2}\\
&= \delta\lambda\\
& \le \varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration.